# Plotting Likert Data with the Likert Package - Returning Median instead of Mean

Tags: r, likert

I'm trying to visualise likert type data with the `likert` package.
The following code gives me the following plot:

```
plot(likert(data_frame), type = "heat")
```

[image]

In the likert heat map the second column (next to the item names) is called "Mean (SD)" and gives the mean and it's SD. However, I'd prefer to be either given the median and its SD, just the median or the total number of answers/respondents, instead of mean (sd).
Is there an easy way of doing this with the `likert` package or is it best to try visualise with `ggplot2` and without the `likert` package?

Best regards from Berlin!

Comment: It's not impossible, but it doesn't exist as an option within the package itself, so it would require overwriting some of the functions within the package to achieve. I think it's best to look at alternatives first.

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)